# RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/xml;charset=UTF-8

Tags: kotlin, client, resteasy, jackson2

I'm a newbie in a REST services, but all solutions I found was due to lack of necessary providers.

Dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-client', version: '3.6.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.6.1.Final'
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.+"
```

Data class:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Response")
data class ResponseSessionInit(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Error") val error: Error)
data class Error(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Text", isAttribute = true) val text: String)
```

Proxy:

```
interface L3Client {

  @POST
  @Consumes("text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
  @Produces("text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
  fun test(string: String): ResponseSessionInit
}
```

Proxy method invocation:

```
    val proxy = client.target(API).proxyBuilder(L3Client::class.java).build()
    println(proxy.test("<Request><ProtocolInfoGet/></Request>"))
```

I receive exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/xml;charset=UTF-8 and type class ru.abinet.commons.cft.L3.messages.ResponseSessionInit

at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:156)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:60)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:150)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.test(Unknown Source)
```

It really looks like if Resteasy client can't find a decoder for my XML, however I have it in path.

I can change test() method to return String and successfully parse XML with something like

```
    val mapper = XmlMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
    val value = mapper.readValue(xml, ResponseSessionInit::class.java)
```

However, I'd like to do it automagically. What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasteasy can't handle application/xml content-type out of the box with jackson-xml. So the idea is to write it by yourself.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
class BodyReaderProvider : MessageBodyReader<Any> {

   //jackson instantiation and some check code here
}
```

and register it

```
val client = ResteasyClientBuilder.newBuilder()
               .register(BodyReaderProvider())
```